# How to update an array in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am struggling to find a suitable logic to update this array in Laravel. With this same logic I can create however with I try to update It does only updates the last row of the array. thanks

here is the code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

$invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);

$invoice->invoice_no = $request->invoice_no;
$invoice->client = $request->client;
$invoice->title = $request->title;
$invoice->client_address = $request->client_address;
$invoice->invoice_date = $request->invoice_date;
$invoice->due_date = $request->due_date;
$invoice->subtotal = $request->subtotal;
$invoice->grandtotal = $request->grandtotal;

$invoice->save();

$products = $request->all();


  $name = $products['name'];
  $price = $products['price'];
  $qty = $products['qty'];
  $total = $products['total'];

 foreach( $name as $key => $n) {

    $invoice->products()->update([ 

         //=> $invoice->id,
        'name' => $name[$key],
        'price' => $price[$key],
        'qty' => $qty[$key],
        'total' => $total[$key]
    ]);
 }
```

with this exactly code I can create and works fine but if i try to update it only update the last record in the array.

database

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('invoice_no');
    $table->date('invoice_date');
    $table->date('due_date');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('client');
    $table->string('client_address');
    $table->decimal('subtotal');
    $table->decimal('grandtotal');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

products

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('invoice_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('qty');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->string('total');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

relationship

```
class Invoice extends Model {
protected $fillable =['client','client_address','title','invoice_no','invoice_date','due_date','discount', 'subtotal','grandtotal'];



public function products(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'invoice_id');
}


class Product extends Model
{

protected $casts = [
'name' => 'array',
'price' => 'array',
'qty' => 'array',
'total' => 'array'
];
protected $fillable = ['invoice_id','price','qty','total','name'];


public function invoice(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');

}
}

array:13 [▼
"_token" => "RBtz42WyWeebnDTrSkhVhN2XC00f7MhyihI08lvA"
"invoice_no" => "1234"
"client" => "Denisson de Souza"
"title" => "owner"
"client_address" => "20/590 pine ridge road"
"invoice_date" => "2017-09-25"
"due_date" => "2017-09-30"
"name" => array:4 [▼
  0 => "11"
  1 => "22"
  2 => "33"
  3 => "44"
]
"price" => array:4 [▼
  0 => "32"
  1 => "32"
  2 => "32"
  3 => "32"
]
 "qty" => array:4 [▼
0 => "1"
1 => "2"
2 => "3"
3 => "4"
]
"total" => array:4 [▼
0 => "32"
1 => "64"
2 => "96"
3 => "128"
]
"subtotal" => "93.00"
"grandtotal" => "106.00"
]
```

Comment: Please add the code that is calling update() to your post

Comment: what does $products look like? can you print_r() or var_dump() it?

Comment: what is in the product update function?

Comment: this line is going to get all of the products associated with the invoice: $invoice->products(), so they calling update() on that doesn't make much sense. You would need to loop over all the products returned and update each one, which is why I was looking for a $product->update() method

Comment: I understand that but I can't find the right logic. stuck on it for past 2 days and i can't figure out nor find anything online, tried documentation too and not working, can you help me pls

Comment: Are the product name unique? You should include the ids in your form: <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{ $product->id }}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

Add another hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{ $product->id }}">
```

Then replace your foreach loop with the following:

```
$productObjs = Product::where('invoice_id', $invoice->id)->get(); 
foreach($productObjs as $prod){
    $key = array_search($prod->id, $products['id']);
    $prod->name = $name[$key];
    $prod->price = $price[$key];
    $prod->qty = $qty[$key];
    $prod->total = $total[$key];
    $prod->save();

}
```

Comment: thanks i-man, however it is not working, it's still updating the last result and not each one of them.

Comment: hi i-man, i have done some changes in your code, took the arrow out to = and added semicolon however this code is not saving anything, it's still the same text, so not updating. weird.

Comment: var_dump($productObjs);

Comment: I man I have found the solution, thanks to you. the only change I did it was $productObjs = Product::where('invoice_id', $invoice->id)->get(); and works fine now